# How to extract NULL and empty strings from MySQL into csv using Python with "" for empty string and nothing (not even quotes) for NULL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to select specific columns from a MySQL table into csv.
This table has integers, varchar, NULL and empty strings.
I want to differentiate between NULL and empty strings in specific way.

For DB row content: `ABC, 123,,NULL,2022-12-22`

The csv should have: `"ABC"|"123"|""||"2022-12-22"`

Is there any way to do this using Python **without having to do row level operations**?

I am trying to use Pandas and csv modules (open for other options as well) but couldn't find a way to represent DB NULL with nothing and empty string with "".

In csv I get either

"ABC"|"123"|""|""|"2022-12-22" `#df.to_csv(r'file_name.csv', index=False, sep='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, na_rep=None)`

OR

"ABC"|123|""|""|"2022-12-22" `#df.to_csv(r'file_name.csv', index=False, sep='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, na_rep=None)`

OR

ABC|123|||2022-12-22 `#df.to_csv(r'file_name.csv', index=False, sep='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, na_rep=None)`

My complete code is:

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import csv
 
mydb = mysql.connector.connect (
    host = "hostname",
    user = "user_name",
    password = "pwd",
    database = "db_name"
)
 
sqlquery = pd.read_sql_query('''select * from db_name.table_name''')
 
df = pd.DataFrame(sqlquery)
df.to_csv(r'file_name.csv', index=False, sep='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, na_rep=None)
```

I have checked many SO posts like following but none give the solution I am looking for:

[Writing-empty-string-with-quotes-and-null-value-without-quotes-while-writing-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72745917/writing-empty-string-with-quotes-and-null-value-without-quotes-while-writing-to)

[dont-convert-null-value-to-empty-string-when-exporting-mysql-data-to-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59173458/dont-convert-null-value-to-empty-string-when-exporting-mysql-data-to-csv)

[writing-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-csv-file-with-some-empty-rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665141/writing-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-csv-file-with-some-empty-rows)